# How to extract a class name from filename of a video?

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, keras

I want to extract a class name from a file name and write it to a `.txt` file. I tried to create a function based on [this work](https://github.com/dipakkr/3d-cnn-action-recognition).

The `videoto3d.py` and `3dcnn.py` are the ones I should change, but I didn't quiet understand what should I do to get the function I need. Specifically I don't understand what the `vid3d` is for.

My dataset is :

```
-video
  -- drink
     --a01_s01.avi
     --a01_s02.avi
     --a02_s01.avi 
  -- eat 
     --a03_s01.avi
     --a04_s01.avi 
   .....
```

I did write a simple function that only extract the folder name

```
import os 
    
import numpy as np
import cv2
labellist=[]
nclass=16 #number of classes 
labels = []

path= '/video'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
   print(filename)
   
   label =  filename[filename.find('_') + 1:filename.find('_', 2)]

   if label not in labellist:
     
   if len(labellist) >= nclass:
         
   labellist.append(label)
 
   labels.append(label)
 
with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
   for i in range(len(labellist)):
      file.write('{}\n'.format(labellist[i]))
```

But, like I said, this only gives me the names of the folders.

What Iwant to have is somthing like this :

```
drink/a01_s01 1
drink/a01_s02 1
eat/a02_s01 2
eat/a02_s02 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the class name from a video file name and write it along with the file name to a text file. Based on your folder structure and file naming convention, you can modify your code as follows:

```py
import os

dataset_path = '/video'

def extract_class_name(file_name):
    class_name = file_name.split('_')[0]
    return class_name

with open('result.txt', 'w') as file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dataset_path):
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith('.avi'):  # Filter for video files
                class_name = extract_class_name(file_name)
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                file.write('{} {}\n'.format(file_path, class_name))
```

In this code, the extract_class_name function takes a file name as input and splits it based on the underscore character (_). It returns the first part of the split, which represents the class name.

The code then walks through the directory tree rooted at dataset_path using os.walk. For each video file, it extracts the class name using the extract_class_name function, creates the file path by joining the root path and file name, and writes the file path and class name to the result.txt file.

Make sure to update the dataset_path variable with the correct path to your video dataset. This code assumes that the videos are directly contained in the class folders, as you mentioned in your directory structure example.

After running this code, the result.txt file should contain lines in the format file_path class_name, where file_path represents the full path to the video file and class_name is the extracted class name.

Please note that this code assumes that all video files have the .avi extension. Adjust the file extension check (if file_name.endswith('.avi')) accordingly if your videos have a different extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use the pathlib library?
Using that you could get the name of the file with `stem` and go up your directory tree with `parent` and get the names with `name`.
for example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path('/root/folder1/folder2/file.txt')
print(dir.stem)
print(dir.parent.name)
print(dir.parent.parent)
```

will print out:

```
file
folder2
/root/folder1
```